# Applying a specific table format to all tables in a Powerpoint presentation (Border, size, multi-colored cells)

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have asked previously how I would modify some code to change the color of tables, which worked wonderfully. But now I am told I need to follow a specific style, which includes multiple colors, a specific border, and for the borders to positioned in a specific way. [image: I can attach an image of what was requested from me.]

I tried modifying the code that someone helped me with on this forum previously, but I can't seem to find out how to apply different colors to each column, or to set border color and thickness. Here's what I've come up with, I managed to figure out how to set the column width, but I didn't even know where to start with the different colored cells, and the border function mostly works but doesn't change the leftmost border of the table. [image: but doesn't change the leftmost border of the table.]

```
Sub ChangeTableColor()
  Dim oSlide As Slide
  Dim oShape As Shape
  Dim oBorder As Borders
  Dim oTable As Table
  Dim i As Long, j As Long
  For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
      If oShape.HasTable Then
        Set oTable = oShape.Table
        For i = 1 To oTable.Rows.Count
          For j = 1 To oTable.Columns.Count
            oTable.Cell(i, j).Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(100, 100, 100) 'Not sure how to make this line do different colors for different cells.
            oTable.Columns(1).Width = (1.9 * 72)
            oTable.Cell(i, j).Borders(ppBorderBottom).ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            oTable.Cell(i, j).Borders(ppBorderTop).ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            oTable.Cell(i, j).Borders(ppBordeLeft).ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            oTable.Cell(i, j).Borders(ppBorderRight).ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
          Next j
        Next i
      End If
    Next oShape
  Next oSlide
End Sub
```

I apologize if this is a silly question, to be quite honest I have nearly no experience coding and I'm just trying to automate something for my work. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks to user @taller_ExcelHome on this forum for help with the base code.

Comment: All tables have no more than 4 rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color of the table cells can be set using `Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB`. The weight of the table borders can be accessed through `Borders(..).Weight`.
Note: The provided code may need to be adapted if the tables have more than 4 rows.

```
Sub ChangeTableColor()
    Dim oSlide As Slide
    Dim oShape As Shape
    Dim oBorder As Borders
    Dim oTable As Table
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim aColor, bColor As Long, iBorder As Integer
    aColor = Array(&HB8DFCA, &HD0F2FD, &HDBF0E5, &HF6EBE0)
    bColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
            If oShape.HasTable Then
                Set oTable = oShape.Table
                oTable.Columns(1).Width = (1.9 * 72)
                For i = 1 To oTable.Rows.Count
                    For j = 1 To oTable.Columns.Count
                        If i < 4 Then ' if all tables have no more than four rows
                            oTable.Cell(i, j).Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = aColor(i - 1)
                        End If
                        For iBorder = 1 To 4
                            With oTable.Cell(i, j).Borders(iBorder)
                                .ForeColor.RGB = bColor
                                .Weight = 5
                            End With
                        Next iBorder
                    Next j
                Next i
            End If
        Next oShape
    Next oSlide
End Sub
```

[image]